# I can't install HAXM even after trying everything

Tags: android-studio, intel, haxm

I initially tried to install haxm though android studio. Not working.
I downloaded the installer for haxm though intel. Not working because: VT-x is not supported by this computer or it is being exclusively used by Hyper-V.

But vt is supported and it's not used by hyper-v.

I checked windows feautures and all hyper-v options/suboptions are off. I checked windows defender -> core isolation -> memory integrity and it's off. I have no other antivirus software that could possible block hyper-v, I have only windows defender.

I tried turning off, in case it's on, with command line and then rebooted and tried installing again.

I checked the bios/uefi and vt is enabled, mts (multithreading) is enabled.

I checked windows services and there was no service, relative to hyper-v, running.

I don't believe that there might be another software running in the same time which causes this problem (like amd driver (andrenaline), asrock rgb, or I don't know what).

Any idea?

CPU : ryzen 5 2600. MOBO: Asrock Fatal1ty B450 Gaming K4. OS: Windows 10 Education (latest version)

(I am not sure if this post fits here but I have seen a couple of posts regarding installation problems of HAXM. I read them. Still, they're not helpful for my problem as it seems)

Answer (score 0):

Do check the following things

- go to **BIOS** of your system, if your system (laptop/desktop) have **intel** processor then enable the **VT-X** (virtualization technology).
- if your laptop/desktop have **AMD** processor then enable **HYPER-V** form your **BIOS**.

This will fix your problem for sure. If not then try to update your **BIOS**.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it having the following settings:

Under advanced/cpu settings:
SVM enabled. MTS enabled.

Under advanced/northbridge:
SR-IOV enabled.

On windows:
Hyper-V off. Windows Hypervisor on.

On windows defender:
Core Isolation -> Memory Integrity: off

On android studio:
Settings/System Settings/Android SDK: 
Android Emulator On
Android Emulator Hypervisor Driver for AMD Processors On

(Check running services for related tasks. Check 3rd party software)

Reboot.

**Don't try to install Intel x86 Emulator Accelator(HAXM) with AMD. There is no way to do it with AMD.**